# Одно и то же действие при клике

Tags: c#, winforms

В каждой .cs форме есть одна и то же меню, с одними и теми же списками и действиями по клику на них. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не вызывать их каждый раз из этой формы, а глобально?

Пока в каждой форме такой, например, код:

```
private void настройкиToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings frm = new Settings();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Приходится копировать его из формы в форму, как избежать этого?

Comment: если все формы имеют одинаковый функционал (не обязательно во всем), то соберите одинаковый функционал в одном классе формы, опишите все нужные методы, и наследуйте все остальные формы от него. ООП для того и нужен.

Comment: Можно сделать построение меню функцией, которая будет одна на всех, или сделать команду (ICommand) вообще.

Comment: @Monk IComand вряд ли подойдет, судя по обработчику там WinForms

Comment: Наследовать не получится, так как класс формы уже наследует стандартный Form, а более 1 класса наследовать нельзя. Или придется этот вспомогательный класс наследовать от Form, а саму форму уже от него.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский естественно, создаем вспомогательный класс с наследование от Form, пихаем в него все что нужно всем остальным, и от него наследуемся дальше, дополняя по необхлдимости недостающее

Comment: Вам нужно выделить визуальную и функциональную часть отдельно.
Функциональную описать в виде класса, визуальная - форма.
Получится что у вас будут все формы обращаться к 1 методу класса и не придется везде копировать этот код, но можно использовать события.
Ведь каждый клик кнопки - событие, привяжите событие клика к собственному методу обработки необходимого класса.